# Kendo Toolbar using HTML.RenderAction() using MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to add a rendered action into a toolbar:

```
 .ToolBar(t=>t.Template(@<text>
         @Html.RenderAction("DisplayAccountDropDown", "ClientAccountState");
         <button class="k-button" id="clearFilter">Clear</button>
         <a class="k-button" href="@Url.Action("Export", "Holdings")" >Export</a>
      </text>))
```

But the Html.RenderAction doesn't have a return value to render. Is there a way to get the output of the action into the toolbar? I am converting an app to use Kendo so would rather not have to change the controller if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @Html.Action this will return you MvcHtmlString instead.